# Clock inside a table?

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, qtableview, qtimer

I created a table with 6 column with different field (ID, name ecc...). I can insert rows.
My question is about showing the current time every time I Insert a new rows.
I follow the tutorial inside QT Model-View ( https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/modelview.html) , but every time I insert a new row, every clock reset with the current time and every time I scroll the table, all the clock reset with the current time.
Could you help me please.
Im gonna link the code down below.

//******************MODEL.H******************//

```
class QTableModelAdapter : public QAbstractTableModel
{

Q_OBJECT

public:

MyModel(QObject *parent);

int rowCount(const QModelIndex& = QModelIndex()) const override;

int columnCount(const QModelIndex& = QModelIndex()) const override;

QVariant data(const QModelIndex&, int = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;

QTimer *timer;

private slots:

void timerHit();

};
```

//******************MODEL.CPP******************//

```
QTableModelAdapter::QTableModelAdapter(QObject *parent)
:QAbstractTableModel(parent)

{

timer = new QTimer(this);

timer->setInterval(1000);

connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()) , this, SLOT(timerHit()));

timer->start();

}


QVariant QTableModelAdapter::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const {

if (!index.isValid() || index.row() >= model->count() || index.row()<0)

    return QVariant();

switch(role){

case Qt::BackgroundColorRole:

    return QVariant(QBrush(QColor(Qt::white)));

case Qt::TextAlignmentRole:

    return QVariant ( Qt::AlignVCenter | Qt::AlignHCenter );

case Qt::SizeHintRole:

    return QSize(500, 0 );

case Qt::EditRole:

case Qt::DisplayRole:

{
    switch(index.column())

    {

    case 0:

        return QTime::currentTime().toString();

    case 1:

         ...
```

Comment: You need to cache the value of `QTime::currentTime()` when you create a new row/model. You could keep a simple `QVector<QTime>`, for example, and index into it using `index.row()`. All the business with `QTimer` is for refreshing the table every second, that is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Can you give me an example please? I don't understand how to implement it

Comment: Add `QVector<QTime> times` to your class. in case 0 of `Qt::DisplayRole`, `return times[index.row()].toString();`. Whenever you add a new row, call `times.append(QTime::currentTime());`. When you remove rows, remove the corresponding elements from `times` again.

Comment: Where does your `MyModel` class store the data for the other columns? How do you track edits to those?

Comment: I implement DataSerialize and DataUnserialize in order to save everything in a XML files. It's a university project, I really appreciate your help I hope to solve this, I have very little time to finish this

Comment: So can you please show the full code that actually contains data? Do you save _everything_ to a file on _every_ change? Where do you add new rows?

Comment: This is the full project. You can just take a look at QTableModelAdapter. If you can give me the code I have to add it would be great! Still can't solve it. https://github.com/DanielJamesTronca/P2_Project. I implement my own Container, other stuff are GUI and hierarchy. Thanks very much bro!

Comment: So your Model is in fact a container of Help_Desk items. Add a QTime field to the class Help_Desk and create a getter for it. On [creation](https://github.com/DanielJamesTronca/P2_Project/blob/master/help_desk.cpp#L6), initialize this field to `QDir::currentTime()`.  Then all that remains in your `QTableModelAdapter::data` method is to retrieve the time of the ticket much like you do [below](https://github.com/DanielJamesTronca/P2_Project/blob/master/qtablemodeladapter.cpp#L90) for its ID.

Comment: Derp. `QTime::currentTime()` of course.

Comment: You mean like this : Help_Desk(unsigned int=1,const std::string& ="No brand", const std::string& ="No name", QTime::currentTime());  ? Because I get error, I really can't understand man, I'm sorry

Comment: As part of the initializer list of the constructor, not an argument: `Help_Desk(unsigned int=1,const std::string& ="No brand", const std::string& ="No name") : time(QTime::currentTime()), ... { }`

Comment: Great, it works! Last question dude, in QTableModelAdapter::data I retrieve the time like this:   return model->getHelpDesk(static_cast<unsigned int>(index.row()))->getTime();  ? Because it only display hour and minutes, but not seconds! God bless ya btw

Comment: You're not calling `toString()` on the QTime object like before.

Comment: Man I really appreciate your help. I'm about to finish, but I just found a little problem. When I save my file, an XML file is created (and everything works fine), but when I load it only Tipo (Type in English) field is loaded, do you any idea on how to solve it? I'm trying to work on it !! Here is the updated project: https://github.com/DanielJamesTronca/P2_Project

Comment: You should ask a new question about it. Be sure to provide enough information and show that you've done your homework.